# Flex how to format a date string when it could be two different formats

Tags: apache-flex, date, format, flash-builder

I have a date field in flex and have the format set to YYYY-MM-DD.  As long as the user clicks the calendar pop-up it set's it that way.

However, I need to allow the field to be human enter-able so they can type in a date.

The problem is, most users want to type the format  MM/DD/YYYY.   I have a tool tip that shows the format, but how can I check the format and change it to the YYYY-MM-DD format, or do something else appropriate (alert?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough:

```
DateFormatter.parseDate(yourString);
```

As long as your string is somewhat of a standard format, it should work.